# Is there a way to get passed in post request parameters during building process in Retrofit2.1.0?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to compute a checksum from HTTP arguments dynamically. And then I would like to add this checksum as an HTTP argument.

I need to get the fields that are passed in as parameters first, but it looks like retrofit can only access url query parameters.

@Gordak shows the way to get query parameter, but what I want to achive, if any possible, to get post parameters in the request chain.

Comment: First, let see if I understood you well. To me, you are trying to compute a checksum from your HTTP arguments dynamically. And then you would like to add this checksum as an HTTP argument. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Gordak exactly, that's what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here we go.

First, build your OkHTTP client and retrofit object.

```
        OkHttpClient client = httpBuilder
                .addNetworkInterceptor(INTERCEPTOR_REQUEST_ADD_CHECKSUM)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl("https://my.domain.com")
                .build();
```

Then, you need to define your interceptor :

```
 private static final Interceptor INTERCEPTOR_REQUEST_ADD_CHECKSUM = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            HttpUrl url = chain.request().url();
            String param1 = url.queryParameter("param1");
            String param2 = url.queryParameter("param2");
            String chk = aMethodToComputeChecksum(param1,param2);

            url = url.newBuilder().addQueryParameter("checksum", chk).build();
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
```

Comment: thank you, since some parameter names are changed for different APIs, I will use queryParameterNames to get all keys, then retrieve their values, because those method are start with query, I skipped those methods at the beginning, I will later to check if it retrieve parameters from request body

Comment: Yes. Then just pass an array (or list) of Strings to the method that computes your checksum ;)

Comment: sorry for late feedback, but it seems no way to get post parameters whcih are build into RequestBody in request chain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help - try to compute this parameter once and write it in RequestInterceptor

Comment: retrofit2 use Interceptor instead of RequestInterceptor, that what I thought, I would like to compute once, but fix args can do so, passed in args are not known at this piont, except that there is a way I can get request parameters during Intercept building process